# Bringing Excel SaveAs Dialog to front Visual Basic (not VBA)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, export-to-excel, savefiledialog

I've written a Visual Basic program that connects to an Access database, makes a few SQL statements, then tries to write it the results to an excel file.

Everything works properly, except when it calls the SaveAs dialog:

```
xlApp.Dialogs(Excel.XlBuiltInDialog.xlDialogSaveAs).Show()
```

The dialog is behind the program, which is maximized.  Thus, the program appears to hang as it's waiting for the dialog to close, but the dialog cannot be accessed (except by Alt+Tab, but that's an ugly workaround).

Any way for me to force the Dialog to the front?  I found a related thread [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vblanguage/thread/e8433d49-442c-4fc0-bef3-031f126b01c6) but I'm not dealing with separate threads.  The OP there suggests the BringToFront method, but I'm not sure on how to use that with my xlApp.Dialogs.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Find the window handle and call [SetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

```vb
Public Function FindWindowByPartialTitle(ByVal _
    TestFlex_string As String) As Long
    m_TestFlexString = TestFlex_string
    m_TestFlexHwnd = 0

    ' Enumerate windows.
    EnumWindows AddressOf EnumCallback, 0

    ' Return the hWnd found (if any).
    FindWindowByPartialTitle = m_TestFlexHwnd
End Function

' Check a returned task to see if it's the one we want.
Public Function EnumCallback(ByVal app_hWnd As Long, ByVal _
    param As Long) As Long
Dim buf As String
Dim title As String
Dim Length As Long

    ' Get the window's title.
    Length = GetWindowTextLength(app_hWnd)
    buf = Space$(Length)
    Length = GetWindowText(app_hWnd, buf, Length)
    title = Left$(buf, Length)

    ' See if the title contains the TestFlex string.
    If InStr(title, m_TestFlexString) <> 0 Then
        ' This is the one we want.
        m_TestFlexHwnd = app_hWnd

        ' Stop searching.
        EnumCallback = 0
    Else
        ' Continue searching.
        EnumCallback = 1
    End If
End Function
```

So with the above function you should be able to do something like:

```vb
Dim saveAsHwnd as Long

call saveAsHwnd = FindWindowByPartialTitle("Save")
call SetForegroundWindo(saveAsHwnd)
```

Don't forget to decalre SetForegroundWindow as well:

```vb
Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
```